# echarts Line charts cannot be updated with timestamp information

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am using echart for line graphing. I am using vue-element-admin. which. It wraps the echart line drawing. We just need to call and pass in the corresponding value. But now I am facing problem. The line chart can only use my data information. It doesn't use my timestamp message. It can't render my timestamp to the page.

### My code.

```
<template>
  <div class="dashboard-editor-container">
    <github-corner class="github-corner"/>

    <panel-group @handleSetLineChartData="handleSetLineChartData"/>

    <el-row style="background:#fff;padding:16px 16px 0;margin-bottom:32px;">
      <line-chart :chart-data="lineChartData"/>
    </el-row>
    <h1>{{ lineChartData }}</h1>
    <el-row :gutter="32">
      <el-col :xs="24" :sm="24" :lg="8">
        <div class="chart-wrapper">
          <raddar-chart/>
        </div>
      </el-col>
      <el-col :xs="24" :sm="24" :lg="8">
        <div class="chart-wrapper">
          <pie-chart/>
        </div>
      </el-col>
      <el-col :xs="24" :sm="24" :lg="8">
        <div class="chart-wrapper">
          <bar-chart/>
        </div>
      </el-col>
    </el-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PanelGroup from './components/PanelGroup'
import LineChart from './components/LineChart'
import RaddarChart from './components/RaddarChart'
import PieChart from './components/PieChart'
import BarChart from './components/BarChart'

const lineChartData = {
  newVisitis: {
    expectedData: [],
    actualData: [] // 添加 actualData 数组
  }
  // 其他数据...
}

export default {
  name: 'DashboardAdmin',
  components: {
    PanelGroup,
    LineChart,
    RaddarChart,
    PieChart,
    BarChart
  },
  data() {
    return {
      lineChartData: lineChartData.newVisitis
    }
  },
  computed: {
    chartData() {
      return {
        xAxis: {
          data: this.lineChartData.actualData,
          boundaryGap: false,
          axisTick: {
            show: false
          }
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: 'Expected Data',
            type: 'line',
            data: this.lineChartData.expectedData
          }
        ]

      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.setupWebSocket()
  },
  methods: {
    handleSetLineChartData(type) {
      this.lineChartData = this.lineChartData[type]
    },
    setupWebSocket() {
      const socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/api/monitoring/ws')
      socket.onmessage = (event) => {
        const [timestamp, newData] = event.data.split(',')
        const parsedTimestamp = timestamp // 存储原始时间戳字符串
        const parsedNewData = parseInt(newData)

        this.lineChartData.actualData.push(parsedTimestamp)
        this.lineChartData.expectedData.push(parsedNewData)

        // 可以考虑保持数组长度，例如只保留最近的 N 个数据
        if (this.lineChartData.expectedData.length > 10) {
          this.lineChartData.actualData.shift()
          this.lineChartData.expectedData.shift()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.dashboard-editor-container {
  padding: 32px;
  background-color: rgb(240, 242, 245);
  position: relative;

  .github-corner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    border: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  .chart-wrapper {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 16px 16px 0;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .chart-wrapper {
    padding: 8px;
  }
}
</style>
```

### encapsulated code

```
<template>
  <div :class="className" :style="{height:height,width:width}" />
</template>

<script>
import echarts from 'echarts'
require('echarts/theme/macarons') // echarts theme
import resize from './mixins/resize'

export default {
  mixins: [resize],
  props: {
    className: {
      type: String,
      default: 'chart'
    },
    width: {
      type: String,
      default: '100%'
    },
    height: {
      type: String,
      default: '350px'
    },
    autoResize: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    },
    chartData: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chart: null
    }
  },
  watch: {
    chartData: {
      deep: true,
      handler(val) {
        this.setOptions(val)
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.initChart()
    })
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    if (!this.chart) {
      return
    }
    this.chart.dispose()
    this.chart = null
  },
  methods: {
    initChart() {
      this.chart = echarts.init(this.$el, 'macarons')
      this.setOptions(this.chartData)
    },
    setOptions({ expectedData, actualData } = {}) {
      this.chart.setOption({
        xAxis: {
          data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
          boundaryGap: false,
          axisTick: {
            show: false
          }
        },
        grid: {
          left: 10,
          right: 10,
          bottom: 20,
          top: 30,
          containLabel: true
        },
        tooltip: {
          trigger: 'axis',
          axisPointer: {
            type: 'cross'
          },
          padding: [5, 10]
        },
        yAxis: {
          axisTick: {
            show: false
          }
        },
        legend: {
          data: ['expected', 'actual']
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'expected', itemStyle: {
            normal: {
              color: '#FF005A',
              lineStyle: {
                color: '#FF005A',
                width: 2
              }
            }
          },
          smooth: true,
          type: 'line',
          data: expectedData,
          animationDuration: 2800,
          animationEasing: 'cubicInOut'
        },
        {
          name: 'actual',
          smooth: true,
          type: 'line',
          itemStyle: {
            normal: {
              color: '#3888fa',
              lineStyle: {
                color: '#3888fa',
                width: 2
              },
              areaStyle: {
                color: '#f3f8ff'
              }
            }
          },
          data: actualData,
          animationDuration: 2800,
          animationEasing: 'quadraticOut'
        }]
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**When I pass in my message. He can never render the timestamp. It always prints the day of the week**

**My original message body looked like this.**

```
{ "expectedData": [ 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 5, 0, 2, 1, 1 ], "actualData": [ "\"2023-08-26T21:39:10.987278", "\"2023-08-26T21:39:11.999955", "\"2023-08-26T21:39:13.006988", "\"2023-08-26T21:39:14.028521", "\"2023-08-26T21:39:15.010892", "\"2023-08-26T21:39:16.024101", "\"2023-08-26T21:39:17.023636", "\"2023-08-26T21:39:18.018688", "\"2023-08-26T21:39:19.029834", "\"2023-08-26T21:39:20.027650" ] }
```

I tried to pass the message in directly but it doesn't work.Try using Google search. But I didn't search either